# choose which result to return on GROUP BY row

Tags: mysql

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT domain, done FROM tasks WHERE 1 GROUP BY domain
```

Obviously I can get it to return the max value of "done" with MAX(done), but how do i get it to return that whole row?

In the situation I'm in, I have a table with the following rows:

```
domain = somedomain.com, done = 12:27:39, somecolumn = pink
domain = somedomain.com, done = 13:27:39, somecolumn = blue
domain = somedomain.com, done = 14:27:39, somecolumn = orange
domain = anotherdomain.com, done = 07:27:39, somecolumn = orange
domain = anotherdomain.com, done = 09:27:39, somecolumn = pie
```

Using the query above, it returns the following 2 rows:

```
domain = somedomain.com, done = 13:27:39, somecolumn = blue
domain = anotherdomain.com, done = 09:27:39, somecolumn = pie
```

I need to return these 2 rows:

```
domain = somedomain.com, done = 14:27:39, somecolumn = blue
domain = anotherdomain.com, done = 09:27:39, somecolumn = pie
```

Appreciate the help :).

Comment: oops, apparently I wasn't very clear.  My table contains various domains, all with multiple entries.  I want to return the latest row for each domain.  I have updated the original question to better explain what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest one:

```
SELECT done,somecolumn FROM tasks ORDER BY done DESC LIMIT 1;
```

For more elaborate queries, left joins or subqueries may be needed, but this one is pretty straight forward.

---

For the heck of it, if you indeed need other data:

(1) NOT EXISTS:

```
 SELECT a.*
 FROM tasks a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM tasks b
    WHERE b.domain = a.domain AND b.done > a.done);
```

(2) LEFT JOIN

```
 SELECT a.*
 FROM tasks a
 LEFT JOIN tasks b
 ON b.domain = a.domain AND b.done > a.done
 WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

(3) ROWNUMBER() like:

```
SELECT numbered.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        @row := IF(@old_domain = domain,@row + 1,1) as rownumber,
        @old_domain := domain as domain,
        done,
        somecolumn
    FROM tasks
    JOIN (SELECT @old_domain:=0,@row:=0) void
    ORDER BY domain ASC, done DESC
) numbered
WHERE numbered.rownumber = 1;
```

Which one will give you better performance hugely depends on the dataset, so I'd just test those.

Comment: thanks for your reply, evidently my explanation wasn't very clear, I've updated above :)

Comment: thanks Wrikken, unfortunately all 3 examples above just return all 5 of my test rows

Comment: Then probably something about the data is not like I expected. For instance, I expect the `id`  to remain consistent for a domain. If not, substitute all `id` mentions with `domain`.

Comment: ahhh, thanks Wrikken, the first works when I substitute id with domain :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE done = (SELECT Max(done) FROM tasks)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, evidently my explanation wasn't very clear, I've updated above :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    *
from
    tasks
where
    `done`=(select max(`done`) from tasks)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, evidently my explanation wasn't very clear, I've updated above :)